# Tomcat server creation in Android Studio

Tags: android, tomcat, android-studio

I am developing an application which requires setting up a Tomcat server. But in Android Studio, I am unable to find how to add Tomcat servers. Can anyone help me out on that?

Comment: Android Studio is *very* focused on Android development. If you want to be developing for other things (e.g., J2EE with Tomcat), you may wish to consider using another IDE, like IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Actually I need tomcat server to implement websockets. How can I do that in Android studio?

Comment: I am not aware that Android Studio has a way for you to manage Tomcat. Android Studio can help you write the *client* side, but for the server side, you would need to use other tools AFAIK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio does not provide any integration with Tomcat. You need to either manage your Tomcat server outside of the IDE, or switch to IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate which provides both the Android development features from Android Studio and integration with Tomcat.